# Stored procedure datetime invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I'm trying to get date time query to work in stored procedure, but everything I try doesn't work.

Either I get errors or I get results which I'm not expecting like the query statement is not being considered.

This is the value format in the database column I'm trying to query:

```
2019-10-22 02:09:04.953
```

If I open up a new query in SQL Server, and manually write the query it works fine, and I'm getting results after the given date:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order]
WHERE [CreatedOnUtc] > '10/15/2019 13:30:00.000'
ORDER BY [CreatedOnUtc]
```

The datatype of `CreatedOnUtc` is `datetime`

In my code I have tried numerous thing like adding culture info, using to string for formatting, and passing date time to database rather than string:

```
var createFromDate = createdFromUtc.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var createFromDate = createdFromUtc.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
var createFromDate = createdFromUtc.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
var createFromDate = createdFromUtc.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var createFromDate = createdFromUtc.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

This is my stored procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged]
    @CreatedFromUtc NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @CreatedToUtc NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 100 *
                FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order] o WIT H(NOLOCK) '

    SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE o.Deleted = 0'

    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND o.CreatedOnUtc BETWEEN "' +  CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS nvarchar(max)) + '" AND "' +  CAST(@CreatedToUtc AS nvarchar(max)) + '"' -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS datetime) -- + Convert(datetime, @CreatedFromUtc, 126 ) --  --  -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS datetime) -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS nvarchar(max)) -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS datetime) -- + Convert(datetime, @CreatedFromUtc, 101 )  -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS nvarchar(max))  -- 
    END

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

I left some comment out code in the stored procedure so you can see I tried other things. Really not sure where I'm going wrong here.

**UPDATE**
I changed my stored procedure to use date time, and updated my code like so but it still doesn't work.

```
    @CreatedFromUtc DATETIME = NULL    // new parameter declaration
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND o.CreatedOnUtc > ' +  Convert(datetime, @CreatedFromUtc, 101 ) + '' -- AND "' +  CAST(@CreatedToUtc AS nvarchar(max)) + '"' -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS datetime) -- + Convert(datetime, @CreatedFromUtc, 126 ) --  --  -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS datetime) -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS nvarchar(max)) -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS datetime) -- + Convert(datetime, @CreatedFromUtc, 101 )  -- + CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS nvarchar(max))  -- 
    END
```

Also in the query I tried to use `CAST(@CreatedFromUtc AS datetime)` but it still didn't work.

In my C# code, I can confirm the var is a `datetime`.

Now I get the this error in my stack trace

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

[image]

Comment: 1) Why are you using dynamic sql? 2) `Between` won't work as you expect with strings, if you are using dates/datetimes then use the date/datetime datatype if you want correct results.

Comment: It's just another thing I tried, originally I was using ```>``` and ```<```

Comment: @DaleK I also tried using datetime, both sending the datetime variable directly from the code and in stored procedure

Comment: <> won't work correctly with strings either. All comparisons with strings are against their ascii values. Use a datetime datetype and all will be well.

Comment: If the query is exactly the same inside the SP you will get exactly the same results. So something is different.

Comment: @DaleK that's the problem I can seem to figure out what's going on with the query

Comment: You've asked a database date question without indicating what the data type of the column is. Please edit your question and add this.

Comment: Another problem is if you call the procedure without parameters... then @sql will be NULL

Comment: Well the code you are showing, shows a nice simple query outside the SP, and a complex dynamic SQL query inside the SP. Copy the same query in and you will get the same result.

Comment: Yes... there are lots of serious data type issues going on here. Don't ever store a date in a non-date data type. For example your date parameters should not be varchar they should be a date data type

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for the heads up on using datetime and not nvarchar, I only switched to nvarchar due to other stack over flow answers. Also the datetype of that column is datetime when I view the table designer

Comment: @DaleK I copied the same query originally, it did not work. Going to change the code back to use date time and try again, though I feel like I have tried everything

Comment: I have edited the question and added the data type. In summary do two things: 1. Always use dataype `datetime` for this value. 2. Rewrite your proc without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I updated my question, with the datetime example. Thanks. In my stack trace it now says ```Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. ``` I will add that to my question now :)

Comment: @chrisc you are still using dynamic sql... which means you are attempting to convert the datetime into a string, because dynamic sql is executed from a string. Put your actual query in the SP without doing anything dynamic and it will work.

Comment: ...you've just brought C# code into the mix. Goback to basics. Never use VARCHAR for dates. Get your queries working in SSMS. Then talk about C# in a different quesiton. and never say "doesn't work"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the correct datetype i.e. `date` or `datetime2` (`datetime2` is recommended over `datetime`)
2. Don't use dynamic SQL unless you absolutely have to, which is not the case here based on the information provided.

Re-writing your procedure gives:

```sql
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged]
    (
      -- check that the precision matches your needs
      @CreatedFromUtc datetime2(0)
      , @CreatedToUtc datetime2(0)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      SELECT TOP 100 *
      FROM [Test].[dbo].[Order]
      -- Check the >=, < logic is correct for your purposes
      WHERE [CreatedOnUtc] >= @CreatedFromUtc
      AND [CreatedOnUtc] < @CreatedToUtc
      ORDER BY [CreatedOnUtc];

      RETURN 0;
    END

    exec [dbo].[OrderLoadAllPaged] '2019-10-15 13:30:00.000', '2019-10-16 13:30:00.000'
```

Comment: Thanks Dale K, what happens if the dates can possibly be null. Also this section is going to be expanded for many moire parameters.

For example here are a few other parameters ```@OrderStatusId int = 0,
 @PaymentStatusId int = 0,
 @ShippingStatusId int = 0,
 @BillingEmail nvarchar(max) = null,
 @BillingFirstName nvarchar(max) = null,
 @BillingLastName nvarchar(max) = null,```
I have this stored procedure working for all my other 25 parameters, it's just the dates I can't seem to get right

Comment: SO basically it's one giant variable query

Comment: What do you want to happen if the date is null?

Comment: Just add your other parameters? If you have a question about that then feel free to ask another one.

Comment: Skip that part of the procedure

Comment: Do you mean skip that part of the `where` clause? You still want to query based on other inputs right?

Comment: If date are null either use `where (@from is null or datecolumn>=@from)` with parenthesis, or use an isnull `where datecolumn>=isnull@@from,'1900-01-01')`

Comment: @chrisc Please solve this question (date parameters) then ask another about "kitchen sink" stored procedures (stored procedures that take a whole bunch of filter parameters. hint: they are bad)

Comment: @chrisc can we establish whether this solves the specific question you asked? SO question are ideally a single clear question with a single clear answer. If you then have further questions you can open more questions, but lets not answer a whole bunch in the comments.

Comment: Ok so I had to use ```AND [CreatedOnUtc] >= ISNULL(@CreatedFromUtc, '1/1/1900')``` to get it working, however this answer was really helpful and definitely what I needed to get this working. I was going by a default nopcommerce stored procedure which was written up like in my question, and did not realize I could do it this way to. Thanks for helping my DBA skills are not as strong as my codeing skills.

Comment: Please get into the habit of using ISO format. The format you are using is ambiguous. Use `'1900-01-01'`. Using correct formats and data types will remove a lot of fundamental issues you are having.